# NoclassDefFoundError exception when running bat file with external jar

Tags: java

I'm using Eclipse, and in my Java Project, I have added an external jar file. It compiles successfully and run smoothly.

The problem appears when I start to run it outside of Eclipse IDE. I create a bat file in bin folder (the folder where contains all classes have been compiled). This bat file is :

```
java package.ClassToRun
```

but when I execute this bat file, I receive error : `NoclassDefFoundError` because java cannot find class X (class X in my external jar file).

How can I fix this problem. (Mean : I can run this class outside of IDE).

Comment: http://cs.brown.edu/courses/cs015/docs/guide_to_exporting_runnable_jars.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add the external `.jar` to your class-path:

> java -cp /usr/local/jar/foobar.jar
>   com.your.main.classname

---

You could also create a folder (something like `lib`) within the folder where you have the `.jar` file.

`Manifest.MF` contents can be:

```
Main-Class: com.your.main.classname
Class-Path: lib/one.jar lib/two.jar
```

Folder contents:

```
mainFolder/
   * lib/one.jar
   * lib/two.jar
   * my-main.jar
```

To execute:

```
java -jar my-main.jar
```

Comment: Thanks for your detail helping. I think you miss `;` when declare jar . The command should be: `java -cp path_to_jar_file; com.your.main.classname`

Answer (score 1):

You should add external jar to the -classpath while executing the program.